# React native, image component loading an old image associated to that link

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm developing an app for a company and they have provided me with an API from where i can access all the webservices required for the app. The app is suppost to have a profile page, and in this page you can change your picture, i've noticed that in the webservice where the picture is changed, the URL for the image is always the same, so i assume that each time an image is updated, the old one is replaced, the problem is that in react native, the first time i load a profile from a certain account i get the correct image, but if i change the image through their website, and if i load the profile page in the app again, the image loaded is the previous one.
I've tried to do console.log("uri of the image") before the return statement, and the address given is correct, it does lead to the most recent image of that user, the problem is that when used inside an image component, it loads the first image ever corresponded to that URL.

Here's the image component i'm talking about:

```
<Image style={{height:24,width:24,resizeMode:'contain',marginHorizontal:33,marginVertical:21,}} source={{uri:profileImage}}/>
```

Answer (score 2):

Ok so i finally found the solution, just have the image URI like i do

```
source={{ uri: profileImage+ '?' + new Date() }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
  <Image
    style={{
      height: 24,
      width: 24,
      resizeMode: "contain",
      marginHorizontal: 33,
      marginVertical: 21,
    }}
    source={{ uri: profileImage, cache: "reload" }}
  />
```

Comment: Didn't work, its still loading the first ever image that account had.

Answer (score 0):

you can change your uri like this

```
  source={{ uri: profileImage+ '?' + new Date() }}
```

but there is one problem your image will start reload as the componant rerender and this will produce a blink. this was happening in my case. I'll suggest you to append this

```
+ '?' + new Date()
```

when you setstate of profileImage

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar issue when fetching image from AWS S3. The uri remains the same but the actual content/image was changing. This is how I solved it:

1. I created my custom image component which accept `dynamic` property. This is because I wanted to update that component for specific image uri not for all.
2. I then use axios to get response header of the file. This is because aws s3 in response header gives the last updated time of the image.
3. In the end, I concatenate a string at the end of the uri and update the state, so that component rerender.

```
import { StyleSheet, View, Image as NativeImage, ImageProps } from 'react-native'
import React, { useCallback, useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { ActivityIndicator } from 'react-native-paper'
import axios from 'axios';

const Image = (props: ImageProps) => {
    const [path, setPath] = useState("")
    const checkFileMetadata = async () => {
        try {
            const response = await axios.head(props.source.uri)
            setPath(props.source.uri + "?t=" + Date.now(response.headers?.["last-modified"]))
        } catch (error) {
            console.log("error", error)
        }
    }
    useEffect(() => {
        if (props.hasOwnProperty("dynamic")) {
            checkFileMetadata()
        }
    }, [])
    if (props.hasOwnProperty("dynamic")) {
        return (
            <View style={[styles.root, props.style]}>
                {
                    path && (
                        <NativeImage
                            {...props}
                            source={{ ...props.source, uri: path }}
                            style={[styles.imageView, props.style]}
                        />
                    )
                }
                <View style={styles.loaderRoot}>
                    <ActivityIndicator size={18} color='rgba(0,0,0,1)' />
                </View>
            </View >
        )
    }
    return (
        <View style={[styles.root, props.style]}>
            <NativeImage
                {...props}
                style={[styles.imageView, props.style]}
            />
            <View style={styles.loaderRoot}>
                <ActivityIndicator size={18} color='rgba(0,0,0,1)' />
            </View>
        </View >
    )
}

export default Image

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    root: {
        overflow: "hidden"
    },
    imageView: {
        zIndex: 2
    },
    loaderRoot: {
        position: "absolute",
        width: "100%",
        height: "100%",
        alignItems: "center",
        justifyContent: "center",
        backgroundColor: "rgba(0,0,0,0.1)",
        zIndex: 1
    }
})
```

Benefit of using this method is we can make use of React Native Image caching mechanism.